# confusion with the proof of halting problem

Tags: halting-problem

From what I have seen on YouTube such as https://youtu.be/Kzx88YBF7dY?si=5j9tzjMFGCn3aCXW,

We have:
**Halt**: program x input ---> yes halt/ no halt

and **opposite** : halt if Halt returns no halt, and, looping if Halt returns yes halt

so the input of opposite should also be : program x input right? not just a single program.

Hence it does not make sense to feed **opposite** program with just an **opposite** program, what comes after is irrelavnet? not a successful proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The video pretty clearly shows that `OPPOSITE` takes one input `program` and calls `HALT(program, program)`

So `OPPOSITE` takes its input, copies it, and feeds both the input and the copy to `HALT`.

Does that clear your confusion?

Comment: I see it now, thanks. I found this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92WHN-pAFCs, which illustrates your answer and helped me understood.